# Can't identify barcode, Does anyone recognize that type of barcode?

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to read that barcode but unfortunately, it does not seem to be standard barcode types.

Does anyone have experience with barcode types? I want to read then save to my database and re-generate the barcode.

I have tried all online barcode readers but none of recognizing this barcode.

Could they have made their own barcode type or something special?

[image: unknown barcode]

Comment: Looks like Codebar, but without START/STOP/Checksum.  Maybe they found a Codebar font and thought it made a valid barcode?

Comment: Yes, it looks like Codebar I re-generate several times with the same numbers but it does not look like this, and how they read this? I can't read with any barcode reader.